# Losing values in multiple editTextView when I scroll headerListView Android

Tags: android

I had this form, when I scroll (i.e I had the row) I loss my typed values, so my question how I can store values in edittextView, **without using a button valid**, the data will be stored automatically when I finish typing in the edittextview.

[image]

I use a HeaderList View, and this is my Adapter :

```
public class SectionAccompliceAdapter extends com.applidium.headerlistview.SectionAdapter {

private MainActivity mainActivity;
private Realm realm;
private List<Accomplice_groups> accomplice_groupses;
private List<Map<String, Object>> maps;
private Colors colors;
private List<String> mapField, mapFieldSup;
private String value ="";
private FieldFormContact field;


public SectionAccompliceAdapter(MainActivity mainActivity, List<Accomplice_groups> accomplice_groupses, Colors colors) {

    this.mainActivity = mainActivity;
    this.colors = colors;
    realm = Realm.getInstance(mainActivity);


    mapField = new ArrayList<>();

    maps = new ArrayList<Map<String,Object>>();
    this.accomplice_groupses = accomplice_groupses;

}

@Override
public int numberOfSections() {
    return accomplice_groupses.size();
}

@Override
public int numberOfRows(int section)
{
    if(section == -1)
        section = 0;
    return accomplice_groupses.get(section).getAccomplices().size();
}

@Override
public View getRowView(int section, final int row, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Map<String, Object> map;


    final ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        LayoutInflater inflater = mainActivity.getLayoutInflater();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item, null);
        holder.textView1 = (TextInputLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewItem);
        holder.editText1 = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.editTextItem);



        convertView.setTag(holder);

    } else {

        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }


    Accomplice accomplice = accomplice_groupses.get(section).getAccomplices().get(row);// realm.where(Accomplice.class).equalTo("id", id).findFirst();
    if (accomplice != null && accomplice.getField() != null)
    {
        field = accomplice.getField();
        holder.textView1.setHint(field.getLabel());
        holder.editText1.setText(viwer.getData());

        TextWatcher watcher = new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence c, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                mapField.add( editable.toString());

            }

        };
        holder.editText1.addTextChangedListener(watcher);


         holder.editText1.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT);
        InputFilter[] FilterArray = new InputFilter[1];
        FilterArray[0] = new InputFilter.LengthFilter(50);
        holder.editText1.setFilters(FilterArray);



    }

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public Object getRowItem(int section, int row) {
    return null;
}

public List<Map<String, Object>> getMapViews() {
    return maps;
}

public void setMapsViews(List<Map<String, Object>> maps) {
    this.maps = maps;
}

@Override

public View getSectionHeaderView(int section, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (convertView == null) {

            convertView = (TextView) mainActivity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(mainActivity.getResources().getLayout(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1), null);

    }
            section = section+1;
        ((TextView) convertView).setText("Complice : " +section );


    switch (section) {
        case 1:
            convertView.setBackgroundColor(mainActivity.getResources().getColor(R.color.Color_13));
            break;
        ...
    }



    return convertView;
}
@Override
public boolean hasSectionHeaderView(int section) {
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onRowItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int section, int row, long id) {
    super.onRowItemClick(parent, view, section, row, id);

}

class ViewHolder {
    TextInputLayout textView1;
    EditText editText1;
}
```

}

Comment: what's your code for adapter?

Comment: I edit the question can you see,? thank's